# Problems with popover tooltip in table td tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Here is what I have and it works fine:

```
    <div style="padding:5px; border:solid 1px gray; width: 30px; height: 20px;" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-content="test">
        <div class="tv-button"></div>
    </div>
```

But If I do this:

```
<td>
        <div style="padding:5px; border:solid 1px gray; width: 30px; height: 20px;" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-content="test">
            <div class="tv-button"></div>
        </div>
</td>
```

it stopped working.

This is what I have in `script`:

```
    $("[data-toggle=popover]")
        .popover({
            placement: "top",
            trigger: "hover",
            html: true
    });
```

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried changing `.popover` to `td.popover`?

Comment: you're using `data-attributes` and `jQuery` both at once that strange. Btw try writing a `JSfiddle` for better solution.

Comment: This is working http://jsfiddle.net/9977pfd0/

Answer (score 0):

I realized that it does not work if i do the ng-repeat on the "tr" tag and repeat many of "td" tags, in that case it does not work, without ng-repeat it does, i would create JSfiddle but since i have quite a lot of html, i dont want to bother you to read that...did any of you have conclusions about that?